# How do Eldar Rangers get back to their craftworld?

Tags: warhammer-40k

It is known that Eldar Rangers quit the path of the Eldar and left their craftworld. However they are still connected to it. Take Alaitoc for instance, where they still fight for their craftworld on occasion.

How is it possible for them to come back to fight with their peers, do they have access to warp portals? Wouldn't it be dangerous because of deamonic exposure from the Immaterium (or a possessed ranger coming back)?

Comment: I don't have any time or sources on me, but I believe that the Eldar's understanding of warp technology is far more advanced than the Imperium.  In most of the video games, they open up warp portals fairly frequently, though it is not a trivial task.  They do risk demonic corruption (or getting lost in their warp maze or whatever), of a sort, I think, but they are not very susceptible to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Eldar may leave their spiritual path and wander as Rangers, where they perfect their powers of invisibility and stealth, but they never truly leave the Eldar who are a people under siege. Many Rangers prove their worth by scouting out new access gateways to the webway, a technology that once linked all of Eldar space, allowing them to travel instantaneously across that distance.**

All members of the Eldar, even the most disillusioned ones understand the nature of the Eldar's existence as a people now wandering the universe on Craftworlds, without a planet to call home in a very hostile and dangerous universe.

Utilizing their superior spaceship technologies, the Eldar are able to create and maintain webway access points which Rangers who may need to or want to return, are able to do so. Demonic possession happens far less with the Eldar who are wise to the machinations of the beings of the Warp and avoid them using their designated webway portal technology. A webway connection is a stable one and possession is unlikely for anyone traveling there.

The webway was once a galaxy spanning, sophisticated network of paths though the Immaterium connecting all Eldar no matter how far apart they may have been. With the birth of Slannesh, the shockwaves disrupted the Immaterium and much of the webway. Now with the corruption, destruction or loss of knowledge of much of the webway, any paths though it become more precious and the largest ones become staging areas for the Eldar presence.

Many Rangers use their time away to explore the remnants of the webway mapping it for their people's use.

Comment: Very interesting ! Especially when you say that rangers map it for their people's use. From what book does this information comes from ?

Comment: Most of the source materials from the Black Library Series of books as well as the Warhammer 40k gaming books make mention of the Eldar Rangers exploring the webway. Harlequins (whose mental states are often brilliant but questionable) also inhabit the webway seeking ancient archives of Eldar knowledge and technology.

Answer (score 6):

The Eldar have access to the [webway](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Webway), a means of travelling through the Warp. The webway has walls made of psychic resistant material that protects it from the usual perils of the warp. Since the fall of the Eldar it has fallen into a state of disrepair and most maps and routes are lost. However, some remaining Eldar and Dark Eldar still use the webway to travel. It is likely this is how the Eldar are able to return to their craftworlds.

Comment: +1 for the link ! I forgot about the webway and didn't know much details. Mainly knew the  Harlequins living inside of it.